# Python PIL - can't show a picture with Python3.3 on windows 8

Tags: python, module, python-imaging-library

I'm a new user to Python, I have looked for answers all over but haven't really found any posts that helped me.

My question is pretty basic:

I installed the Pillow module using this setup:

```
https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/P/Pillow/Pillow-2.0.0.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=070260925c267318470e8a07251a0ab6
```

I am using windows 8, and python 3.3 for a 32 bit system.
(installed in "C:\Python33\")

I am running this very very simple code:

```
>>> from PIL import Image # no error here

>>> img = Image.open("C:/Users/yoels/Desktop/Pictures/Yoel.jpg") # no errors here

>>> img.show()
```

But instead of showing the picture, Windows 8 open a blank cmd window, 
and raises a notification saying "The app can't open".

I would really apreciate any help! 
Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 1):

and I had a similar problem but instead of blank cmd, I had blank on Photo Viewer, you can first try to associate PNG, JPG to Paint and then:

When Photo Viewer does appear, Go to menu on top: 
**->Open->Choice Program-> Select Paint** 
On Spanish: -> Abrir-> Elegir Programa -> seleccionar Paint

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HN6A.png)